# I don't know how to add path to .dll for Cuda

Tags: path, cuda, addition

I am completely new to CUDA and C. My eventual goal is to adapt a FORTRAN program for CUDA. For now, I am having trouble getting a simple "Hello world" program to run.

I have been able to compile using `nvcc hello_test.cu --machine32` which creates an executable. However when I try to run the .exe, I get a System Error message stating:

> The program can't start because cudart32_32_9.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

I imagine I haven't added the path to this file (which I can find in "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\bin\");  but I don't know how to add the path. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a Fortran compiler available for CUDA so you might not have to translate your program to CUDA C. http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cudafortran.htm (I am not affiliated with them in any way and I have not tried the product).

Answer (score 1):

You can go several routes. Either just make a copy of the DLL and put it in the same directory as your executable.

Or you can add the path you mentioned in the [PATH environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) of Windows. Then it should be able to find the DLL.